# Create a new git repository from a existing local branch

Tags: git, branch

I have a Git repository with two branches: `master` and `redesign`. The `redesign` branch was created from `master`, and `master` has not been touched since then:

```
master
...|--m50--\
            \--m51--|--m52--|--m53-- redesign
```

The `redesign` branch has evolved so much that I would like to create a new whole repository from it, taking the first commit of `redesign` as the initial commit of the new repository and forgetting the previous history inherited from `master`:

```
master
...|--m50--

redesign
--r1--|--r2--|--r3--
```

Is this possible with Git? There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) to this, but its goal is to use a directory, not a branch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could:

- checkout the commit you want for the "root" of your new repo
- copy all the files to your new directory (except the `.git` directory)
- check out your `redesign` branch
- `git format-patch master..redesign`
- move all the generated patch files somewhere handy

Then go to your new directory and:

```
$ git init
$ git add .           # make sure your .gitignore is in place though
$ git commit -m"..."
$ git am /path/to/patches/*.patch
```

Comment: When executing `git am ...` several error messages like these appeared: `/Users/elitalon/Sites/exigo/.git/rebase-apply/patch:447: trailing whitespace` and `error: cake/console/cake.bat: patch does not apply`. What can be happening?

Comment: Use a separate directory where you store *only* the patch files generated by `git format-patch`. What you are trying to apply there doesn't look like anything you should be applying.

Comment: Forget it. I used the flag `--whitespace=fix` and everything worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, copy or clone your git repository.

Then, find out the hash of your new root commit (`m51` in your diagram). Put its commit hash into the file `.git/info/grafts`, then run `git filter-branch --all`. After you have verified the successful operation, you can remove the `original/*` backup refs (or re-clone the repository).

Please note that this will create new commit hashes for all commits, so you have to be careful with already published history.

Answer (score 1):

Create your new repository, then:

```
$ git add remote newrepo <path to newrepo>
$ git checkout redesign
$ git checkout --orphan clean
# The branch is empty, but the files from the original branch are staged for commit.
$ git commit -m"clean"
$ git push newrepo clean:master
```

Note: If you want to preserve history (or don't care), omit the creation of the "clean"

Comment: This was a very simple, straightforward solution; one I hadn't thought of at all, and completely obvious in retrospect (like most simple clever things). Thank you (9 years later, no less). I would only add that, regarding the part about preserving history, this answer does not address the part in the original question about "starting from a specific commit", since the history-preserving variant of this approach will in fact copy all nodes from the very beginning. Nothing that squashing commits later via an interactive rebase can't fix though :)

Answer (score 0):

My method is a bit different. I tested this on my Ubuntu Linux machine. The steps are:

1. Checkout branch / hash that you want to clone or create root repository

   ```bash
   $ git checkout redesign
   ```
2. Make git archive for current branch by using command

   ```bash
   $ git archive HEAD --format zip -o redesign-repository.zip
   ```

   Above command will create a new file called `redesign-repository.zip` in current repository with zip format. We can also change `HEAD` to name / hash of commit, e.g. `git archive redesign --format zip -o redesign-repository.zip`
3. Create a new directory to extract the file to

   ```bash
   $ mkdir ../redesign-repo
   ```
4. Extract the archive to that directory

   ```bash
   $ unzip redesign-repository.zip -d ../redesign-repo
   ```
5. Move to new repository and initialize the new repository with `git init`

   ```bash
   $ cd ../redesign-repo
   $ git init .
   ```

This method will rely on the availability of zip / unzip command. I am not sure if its available on every machine.